# LeetCode 1365 - looking for a better solution than O(n^2)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working leetcode problem number 1365.  Here is the problem below in italicized characters:

*Given the array nums, for each nums[i] find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than it. That is, for each nums[i] you have to count the number of valid j's such that j != i and nums[j] < nums[i].
Return the answer in an array.
Example 1: Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3] Output: [4,0,1,1,3] Explanation:  For nums[0]=8 there exist four smaller numbers than it (1, 2, 2 and 3).  For nums[1]=1 does not exist any smaller number than it. For nums[2]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1).  For nums[3]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1).  For nums[4]=3 there exist three smaller numbers than it (1, 2 and 2).*

https://leetcode.com/problems/how-many-numbers-are-smaller-than-the-current-number/

I am able to complete the task using brute force which gives an O(n^2) time.  Is there a faster way to code this problem?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[] {8,1,2,2,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallerNumbersThanCurrent(nums)));
    }

    public static int[] smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums) {
        int[] result = new int[nums.length];    

        for (int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++) {
            int ctr = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {
                if (nums[y] < nums[x]) {
                    ctr++;
                }
                result[x] = ctr;
            }
        }       
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly better `O(n^2)` approach, where you only compare each pair of indices once and updating the counts accordingly:

```
public static int[] smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums)
{
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < nums.length; y++)
        {
            if (nums[y] < nums[x])
                result[x]++;
            else if (nums[y] > nums[x])
                result[y]++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, at the cost of an additional array we can do it in `O(ngln)` by sorting the indices of the original array and then iterating through these sorted indices, updating the count accordingly. The only complication is in dealing with repeated numbers, e.g. the 2s in your example.

```
public static int[] smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums)
{
    Integer[] idx = new Integer[nums.length];
    for(int i=0; i<idx.length; i++) idx[i] = i;
    Arrays.sort(idx, (a, b) -> (nums[a]-nums[b]));

    int[] res = new int[nums.length];

    for(int i=1; i<idx.length; i++) 
    {
        if(nums[idx[i]] == nums[idx[i-1]])
            res[idx[i]] = res[idx[i-1]];
        else
            res[idx[i]] = i;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Test:

```
int[] nums = new int[] {8,1,2,2,3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallerNumbersThanCurrent(nums)));
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Dang @SirRaffleBuffle!  You are good a t coding algorithms.  Your second solution is more than twice as fast as mine, but holy crap that is complex to wrap my head around.

Comment: @nikotromus Test an input without repeated numbers and print the value of the sorted `idx` array to understand that step. Hopefully then you'll be able to see how walking through this lets you figure out how many numbers come before the corresponding number in `nums`.

Comment: @SurRaffkeBuffle - couldyou do me a big favor and explain this line:  Arrays.sort(idx, (a, b) -> (nums[a]-nums[b]));  Where did 'a' and 'b' come from?

Comment: `a` and `b` will be indexes into the array `nums`. If `nums[a]` is less then `nums[b]` then `a` should come before `b` in `idx`. This is a trick for getting the sorted order of an array while leaving the array untouched. If you sorted `nums` directly you'd lose where the original values were, and wouldn't be able answer the question.

Comment: thanks a bunch.  I understand it.  I will keep revisiting this problem until I can do it with no notes.  I think that this technique of creating a new array and modeling the indexes off of the value in a target array will probably come in handy for other situations.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `O(nlgn)` solution with an `O(n)` space would be:

1. Copy the array into a temp array, `O(n)`
2. Sort the new array `O(ngln)`
3. Iterate over the original array

   - For every element, do a binary search over the sorted array and get the first index of the element.
   - The index would be the count you are after.

Comment: how will you handle duplicates in the array while using a binary search?

Comment: @Raushan you would need to to tweak binary search a. bit to get the first index :)

Comment: If you store the original indices of the array elements before sorting you can avoid the binary searches and just to a linear scan over the sorted array.